# Installing private repository for GitLab on own server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I want to install a private repository of GitLab on my own server. The repository will be hosted on my server, not on the cloud. How can I achieve that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [GitLab Omnibus installation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/), using *one* [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) image with everything in it.
See its [docker manual page](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html).

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://my.domain.com/'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;" \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

That way, you don't have to install manually all GitLab components (ruby, Go, Gitaly, ...): everything is already installed within the Docker image.